# Android Camera Intent woes

Tags: android, android-camera

Hope someone may give some pointers (or an out right answer)...
Simple app, take an image using the built-in camera app, save the image to a separate application.  Be done.

Problem:  The camera application saves the image in the default app location (/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/DCIM/Camera) as well as my custom path (in code below).
Both files are exactly the same except for the file name.  The external_sd file (the one I want gone) is saved with dashes (-) vs my custom file path saved with underscores.  File sizes are exactly the same.

**How can I stop this double image issue?**
Is there an extra intent option I'm missing?
Or am I doing this completely wrong, missing something?
I'm using a Galaxy S Vibrant.

Code snippet:

```
private static Uri _outputFileUri;
private static File _file;
private ImageView _image;
private SimpleDateFormat _simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"); 


    _takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePicture);
    _takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            _intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);          

            _file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                            "/Android/data/my own folder/files/",
                             _simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()).toString() + 
                             ".jpg");

            _outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(_file);

            _intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(_intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY);
        }
    });   


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {  

        case CAMERA_ACTIVITY: 

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                try{
                    Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), _outputFileUri);
                    _image.setImageBitmap(b);
                    _image.invalidate();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is device-dependent behavior.  My observation is that HTC devices do not have this duplication problem, but Samsung devices do.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the following lines:

```
_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                            "/Android/data/my own folder/files/",
                             _simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()).toString() + 
                             ".jpg");

            _outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(_file);

            _intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _outputFileUri);
```

Also update the code to get the image from intent:

```
Bitmap b = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
_image.setImageBitmap(b);
_image.invalidate();
```

This way picture wouldn't be saved on sd card or default location.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and similar.  The problem is 1) Bitmap b = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); only returns a small scaled down gritty image (aka thumbnail) and 2) the full size normal image is still saved in the external_sd default location.

Comment: I tested it in emulator and it don't save image. For image size issue, it seems like bug, please refer to this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/94a5df65f96c5fbe)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and gave up. Sometime later I found out that I was not getting it anymore and I'm not sure what change I made to my code, but I think that it was MediaStore's fault (check my unsolved question: [Weird camera Intent behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079641/weird-camera-intent-behavior))

As you already have the image URI, why don't you use it to set the ImageViews' bitmap?

```
// void setImageURI(Uri uri)
 _image.setImageBitmap(_outputFileUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and here is how i solved it :

```
File createImageFile() throws IOException{

    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String filename = "IMG_"+timestamp+"_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(filename,".jpg",mGalleryFolder );
    if (image.length() == 0 ){
        boolean delete = image.delete();
    }
    mLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

It's not exactly solving but works for me ;)